# Is this not the same logic? Different Results

Tags: c, file, for-loop, io, while-loop

I don't understand how these two codes are giving me different results?

## 1

```
int main()
{

    struct stat buf1;
    struct stat buf2;
    
    FILE *fp1, *fp2;
    int ch1, ch2;
    clock_t elapsed;
    char fname1[40], fname2[40];

    printf("Enter name of first file:");
    fgets(fname1, 40, stdin);
    while (fname1[strlen(fname1) - 1] == '\n')
    {
        fname1[strlen(fname1) -1] = '\0';
    }

    printf("Enter name of second file:");
    fgets(fname2, 40, stdin);
    while (fname2[strlen(fname2) - 1] == '\n')
    {
        fname2[strlen(fname2) -1] = '\0';
    }

    fp1 = fopen(fname1, "r");
    if (fp1 == NULL)
    {
        printf("Cannot open %s for reading\n", fname1);
        exit(1);
    }

    fp2 = fopen(fname2, "r");
    if (fp2 == NULL)
    {
        printf("Cannot open %s for reading\n", fname2);
        exit(1);
    }

    stat(fname1, &buf1);
    size_t size1 = buf1.st_size;

    stat(fname2, &buf2);
    size_t size2 = buf2.st_size;

    printf("Size of file 1: %zd\n", size1);
    printf("Size of file 2: %zd\n", size2);

    elapsed = clock(); // get starting time

    size_t smallest = 0;

    if(size1 < size2)
    {
        smallest = size1;
    }
    else
    {
        smallest = size2;
    }

    int i;

    unsigned long long counter = 0;

    ch1 = getc(fp1);
    ch2 = getc(fp2);

    for(i = 0; i < smallest; i++)
    {       
        ch1 = getc(fp1);
        ch2 = getc(fp2);

        if((ch1 ^ ch2) == 0)
        {
            counter++;
        }
    }
    
    fclose (fp1); // close files
    fclose (fp2);

    float percent = (float)counter / (float)smallest * 100.0f ;

    printf("Counter: %u Total: %u\n", counter, smallest);
    printf("Percentage: %.2f%\n", percent);

    elapsed = clock() - elapsed; // elapsed time
    printf("That took %.2f seconds.\n", (float)elapsed/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    return 0;
}
```

## 2

```
... 

   
    ch1  =  getc(fp1); // read a value from each file
    ch2  =  getc(fp2);

    while(1) // keep reading while values are equal or not equal; only end if it reaches the end of one of the files
    {
        ch1 = getc(fp1);
        ch2 = getc(fp2);
        
        if((ch1 ^ ch2) == 0)
        {
            counter += 1;
        }
   
        total += 1;

        if ( ( ch1 == EOF) || ( ch2 == EOF)) // if either file reaches the end, then its over!
        {
            break; // if either value is EOF
        }
    }
  
    fclose (fp1); // close files
    fclose (fp2);

    float percent = (float)counter / (float)total * 100.0f ;

    printf("Counter: %u Total: %u\n", counter, total);
    printf("Percentage: %.2f%\n", percent);

    elapsed = clock() - elapsed; // elapsed time
    printf("That took %.4f seconds.\n", (float)elapsed/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    return 0;
}
```

The second code gives me higher replication results?? Shouldn't they be the same? Just one is more efficient. I am running the first code with Xeon Phi by adding parallelism, but first, I would like both codes to have the same duplication ratios.

Comment: BTW The first data is discarded.

Comment: They look equivalent, but FWIW, `if ((ch1 ^ ch2) == 0)` can be replaced in both pieces of code by `if (ch1 == ch2)`. `A xor B` is only 0 if `A == B`.

Comment: looks like the you do not get the `size1` `size2` correct.

Comment: To debug this, you could print out a little more, e.g. `count`, `smallest` or `total`, resp., etc. to find out where the problem lies. `smallest` should be the same as `total`. Both values can be compared manually with the actual file sizes too.

Comment: There are a couple of problems with the code.  In both examples, the comparison of the first byte of each file is ignored.  However, the big problem is the stat returns the allocation on disk (some multiple of block size) while the second stops after trying to read past the end of file.  The check for EOF should be BEFORE the check for equality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious difference is that **2** stops when it reads `EOF`, while **1** does not. Actually, `2` counts +1 and then stops when it reads `EOF`. You should do the `EOF` check before incrementing the counter.

If you update **1** to also check for `EOF` you will probably find the same result.

Also it is unclear why you read and discard a character from each file before the start of each loop.

Perhaps you are overlooking that `st_size` might not correspond with the number of readable bytes, especially since you are opening the files as a text stream. (For example, in Windows, `st_size` will count CR-LF as two, but `getc` will only get `\n`).

You could try opening the files in binary mode (`"rb"`). Also it might be enlightening to actually look at the value of `total` in case **2** (and report which file hit `EOF`).

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the off by one byte error, and I will try reading it as a binary file

Answer (score 0):

by examining `if((ch1 ^ ch2) == 0)` you are not counting duplication, you can use `if(ch1 == ch2)` instead

Comment: But that would be comparing addresses and not the bytes, I would like to compare the bytes

Comment: Actually, the if(ch1 == ch2) is comparing the bytes, there are no addresses involved.